# Removed platform from phonegap, now plugin do not work

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I took some terrible advice and removed the ios platform from my phonegap project in order to try to change the bundle identifier. When I re added the ios platform, none of the plugins carried over into the build.

So all of my plugins still exist in the main phonegap project, but when I run cordova platform add ios or cordova build ios, the plugins are not included in that platform, and therefore the app does not function properly inside of xcode.

Does anybody know what I need to do in order to back track and get those plugins to load inside of the ios build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each plugin run `cordova plugin remove` and then `cordova plugin add` again. This is also the process for updating a plugin if you ever need to.

If that doesn't work, you can create a new project and then replace the `www` folder from that project with the one from the original project.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the facebook plugin, but I'm not sure exactly what I should be removing. I tried pulling the names of the plugin from the config.xml but it's saying they are not present in the project. Any idea what that plugin is called?

Comment: try `cordova plugin list`. This should the names of installed plugins. It may not be able to remove them since the platform was removed (a bug with the cli IMO). You may need to create a new project from scratch and then copy over your `config.xml` and `www` folders from the original project. (I end up doing this frequently)

Comment: I was able to uninstall it but when I reinstalled I got an error after trying to build ios. Looks like I'm just going to have to create a new project. Can I just delete the www folder in the new project and paste in the old one?

Comment: Yes, the www folder can be deleted and replaced with the one from your other project.

Answer (score 0):

Trying remove all plugins and then add it again. after this add platform ios and than build the app. if this does not work then create a new cordova project and add plugins.

OR

Try adding plugins manually